# referencing sections in other chapters

Tags: sectioning

Is there a norm for citing sections in other chapters? That is, when I am in Chapter 3 and refer to  section 2 in chapter 2. Do I write "Section 2.2" or "Chapter 2.2" or Section 2 of Chapter 2. Logically Section 2.2 seems to be the correct way, since 2.2 is not a chapter but part of a chapter ... I actually saw all three variants and would like to have this decided once and for all.

Comment: normally the first, the last is OK "Chapter 2.2" just seems wrong. (It's not clear that this question is on topic for this site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the numbering scheme. If you have:

```
Chapter 1
  Section 1.1
  Section 1.2
Chapter 2
  Section 2.1
  Section 2.2
```

Then I would use "Section 2.2", because it's the exact section number used for this section and it's much shorter. Consider referencing a "subsubsection":

```
Subsubsection 2 of Subsection 2 of Section 2 of Chapter 2
```

If the numbering scheme omits the chapter number:

```
Chapter 1
  Section 1
  Section 2
Chapter 2
  Section 1
  Section 2
```

Then the cumbersome referencing scheme applies "Section 2 of Chapter 2" or "Second section in the second chapter".